# How to gather data from a JSON URL and display it

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to write an automated Java test where the code will go to a specified URL, read the JSON data and print it up.
Here is the JSON I am trying to access;

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "records": [

{
            "timestamp": 1381222871868,
            "deviceId": "288",
            "temperature": 17
        },

{
            "timestamp": 1381222901868,
            "deviceId": "288",
            "temperature": 17
        },

{
            "timestamp": 1381222931868,
            "deviceId": "288",
            "temperature": 17
        },

]}
```

As you can see I only have 3 elements, Timestamp, DeviceId and Temperature.

What I am ultimately aiming for it to be able to get 2 Timestamp values and take one value away from the other, if that is possible.

Anyway I have been trying to do this all day and am having no luck whatsoever. I was recommended to use Gson and I have included the jar files into my classpath.

If anyone knows anything or can help me in any way it would be much appreciated as I have exhausted Google and myself trying to work this out.

Here is the code I have to display the full list, but I do not fully understand it and so far can't manipulate it to my advantage;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String jsonString = callURL("http://localhost:8000/eem/api/v1/metrics/temperature/288");
    System.out.println("\n\njsonString: " + jsonString);

    // Replace this try catch block for all below subsequent examples
    /*try 
    {  
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        System.out.println("\n\njsonArray: " + jsonArray);
    } 
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    try 
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        int count = jsonArray.length(); // get totalCount of all jsonObjects
        for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++)
        {   // iterate through jsonArray 
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);  // get jsonObject @ i position 
            System.out.println("jsonObject " + i + ": " + jsonObject);
        }
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String callURL(String myURL) 
{
    //System.out.println("Requested URL:" + myURL);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(myURL);
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        if (urlConn != null)
        {
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
        }
        if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) 
        {
            in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            if (bufferedReader != null) 
            {
                int cp;
                while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) 
                {
                    sb.append((char) cp);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:"+ myURL, e);
    } 

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I doubt you've exhausted Google :). Start by showing us your attempt and why it didn't work.

Comment: ha all the links have already been opened!

Comment: have you looked into the GSON's fromJson ?

Comment: Does this line **System.out.println("\n\njsonString: " + jsonString);** prints any value, if so then please paste that too. If all the values are constant then you could use just one json values right.

Comment: Yes it prints out the list like I have in the question.
The way I need it is to have it just printing out the "timestamp" values and nothing else, but I do not know how to do it that way

Comment: Use Jackson (or GSON) to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I had read the values from file but you can read from URL, the extracting process code is present inside **extractJson()** method.

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("testjson.json");
        int b=0;
        String val="";
        while((b=fis.read())!=-1)
        {
            val=val+(char)b;
        }

        extractJson(val);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void extractJson(String json)
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(json);
        System.out.println("Json object Length: "+jobject.length());
        System.out.println("Status: "+jobject.getString("status"));
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(jobject.getString("records"));
        System.out.println("Json array Length: "+jarray.length());

        for(int j=0;j<jarray.length();j++)
        {
            JSONObject tempObject=jarray.getJSONObject(j);
            System.out.println("Timestamp: "+tempObject.getString("timestamp"));
            System.out.println("Device Id: "+tempObject.getString("deviceId"));
            System.out.println("Temperature: "+tempObject.getString("temperature"));
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

You could use **ArrayList** to store the values which will be available inside **for loop**. From your question you need to pass **jsonString** this variable to the **extractJson()** method. Use **org.json** jar file to process json. If you could alter this for **gson** then it'll be good for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it via Google-Gson

```
class MyRecord
{
private long timestamp;
private String deviceId;
private Integer temperature;
           //Getters & setters
}

public static void main(String... args){
        String myJsonString=callUrl("http://mydomain.com/x.json");
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement ele = jp.parse(myJsonString);

        Gson gg = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyRecord>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<MyRecord> lst= gg.fromJson(ele.getAsJsonObject().get("records"), type);

       //Now the json is parsed in a List of MyRecord, do whatever you want to with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An "high-level" Gson parsing answer:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19252374;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q19252374 {

    class Record {
        Long timestamp;
        String deviceId;
        Long temperature;
    }

    class Container {
        List<Record> records;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"status\": \"success\", \"records\": [{\"timestamp\": 1381222871868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 },{\"timestamp\": 1381222901868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 },{\"timestamp\": 1381222931868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 } ]} ";

        Gson g = new Gson();
        Container c = g.fromJson(json, Container.class);
        for (Record r : c.records)
            System.out.println(r.timestamp);

    }
}
```

Of course this is the result:

> 1381222871868
>
> 1381222901868
>
> 1381222931868